# Как сделать имя таблицы в sqlite3 с черточкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite3

Необходимо сделать имя таблицы в sqlite3 с черточкой, хочу её сохранить и назвать так: SHOPPING-CART, но происходит ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: OperationalError
near "-": syntax error
```

Код с помощью которого пытаюсь это сделать:

```
q = ('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table} (
        userID INT PRIMARY KEY,
        user-cart TEXT
    )''')

sql.execute(q.format(table='SHOPPING-CART'))
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, потому что через DB Browser for sqlite3 спокойно можно это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это плохая идея и не стоит использовать такие имена.
Но так можно сделать. Надо такие названия заключать в двойные кавычки

```
q = ('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table} (
        userID INT PRIMARY KEY,
        "user-cart" TEXT
    )''')

sql.execute(q.format(table='"SHOPPING-CART"'))
```